# android studio flutter error when trying to release the app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, release, android-studio-3.0

i made this app using flutter in android studio and when i try to release the app i get this error:

Error:Android Pre Dex: [flutter.jar] Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView:(Lio/flutter/embedding/engine/systemchannels/PlatformViewsChannel$PlatformViewCreationRequest;)J: invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently 13)

Error:Android Pre Dex: [flutter.jar] Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge.shouldSetCollectionInfo:(Lio/flutter/view/AccessibilityBridge$SemanticsNode;)Z: invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently 13) 11

and this is my flutter doctor output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.864], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (2 months ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 41.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

@Emad, yes. I think you will need to upgrade your Java to 11. [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24238) is more related to this.

Comment: oh yes i saw that before asking here but didn't think that this was my problem, will try it now and i'll update if it fixes my problem

Comment: i downloaded java 11 and installed it, can you lead me to how to reconfigure my IDE to use it? 
1) I went to project structure->SDKS-> added version 11
2) then i went to modules-> here what should i put the module sdk? 
i have many options which are: Project sdk(1.8), 1.8, and 11

**cz now when i try to build the APK i get android sdk not specified**

Comment: Now just add your Android SDK path. Close your project and all other projects and when you're in Android Studio main menu (where you pick your projects) , click Configure at the bottom right -> SDK Manager -> Android SDK (under System Settings) , add your Android SDK location path. which is **C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk** for you. You can also run flutter -v doctor to see if there are any more issues.

Comment: i checked all that and they are already done, my question is inside the project structure cz i think that's where the problem is now, should i change the module sdk path to java 11 too?

Comment: this is exactly the error i'm getting: Error:Android Source Generator: [eppa_app_android] Android SDK is not specified

Comment: something weird just happened, from android studio when i put flutter doctor it gives the same one in my post that licenses are all accepted, but when i try flutter doctor from flutter_console.bat i get this error: 
 Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.

I had this error before, i re-installed sdk manager and it was fixed but this is weird now

Comment: Did you check module settings? right click your project->Open Module Settings->SDK Location .

Comment: i did, it's true, i'm re-downloading android sdk built it worked before, but that what lead me to the original error in my question: Error:java: invalid source release: 11 lol

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's happening here. Did you make sure the JDK Location in your module settings is pointed to your java 11 home and not Android Studios java home?. It normally shows you default location of Android Studios java home.

Comment: it is, this is weird i will try to see what's happening, Thanks a lot man

Comment: No problem. Wish i could help. Good luck!

Comment: i was able to pass this error by modifying my settings but now i get another error which i found solutions on websites but none worked. i will update my question to the new errors

Comment: i fixed it by moving my files to my other pc which had older version of android studio and flutter v1.7.8+hotfix.4 and tried the release through android studio and it worked

Comment: actually things got messed up again :( had some issues after i released the app, when i tried uploading it they gave me an error with zipalign so i did it and after that they told me that i need to resign it and so i did again, after that they told me the app has invalid version code, and another error that the target api is 0 and that it should be at least 28, ps: i released the apk through android studio and I’m sure the version is correct and api too, in the end i came back to the same error in my post and wasn’t able to build the release having same errors :(

Answer (score 0):

If you go to

> File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java
>   Compiler

There's an option to **Use '--release' option** which, if ticked, requires Java 9 or later. Unticking this or updating your Java may solve things for you.

Comment: i just tried it, i unticked the option and tried generating an apk it gave the same error, i'll try updating java

Comment: i downloaded java 11 and installed it, can you lead me to how to reconfigure my IDE to use it? 1) I went to project structure->SDKS-> added version 11 2) then i went to modules-> here what should i put the module sdk? i have many options which are: Project sdk(1.8), 1.8, and 11 cz now when i try to build the APK i get android sdk not specified

Comment: Try looking in:

**Project Structure ->  Platform Settings -> SDK's**

and make sure it's 1.8
 
also Please ensure Java is in your PATH and that JAVA_HOME is defined and pointing to the JDK. I've had Windows put the JRE in the path instead of the JDK, which leads to all kinds of issues.

Please take a look at your PATH environment variable and remove everything Java related that does not point to the JDK folder.

Oracle has some documentation on how to do this here : [Installing Java and setting JAVA_HOME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

Comment: ok i made sure of what you said and put them all correct, one question though when i want to release the app for android, i'm going to **Project Structure -> Modules** and there i have two modules created one which **eppa_app** and the second is **eppa_app_android** i'm adding an *android* module to the second one and fix the path to manifest file, res, and asset folder. am i doing this right?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. I have only one module there and it is my whole flutter project. With just that I can build both and Android and iOS.

Comment: that's why it's driving me crazy lol i still haven't worked around the error hopefully i find a solution

Comment: i was able to pass this error by modifying my settings but now i get another error which i found solutions on websites but none worked. i will update my question to the new errors

Comment: i fixed it by moving my files to my other pc which had older version of android studio and flutter v1.7.8+hotfix.4 and tried the release through android studio and it worked